# How to refresh jquery datatable after deleting a row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Each row in the data table has a delete button.

On click of the delete button, I am calling this code:

```
$('.deleteButton').live('click', function () {

             var $this = $(this);
             var url = $this.attr("id");
             $("#example").fnReloadAjax();
             $.getJSON(url, Success());
         });
```

The url is action of the controller that takes the Id and deletes the data from the database. That works.
I now want to call the refresh/redraw function of datatable so it can load new results but it doesn't work.

Datatable is:

```
 $("#example").dataTable({
             "aoColumns": [
                     { "sTitle": "Id" },
                      { "sTitle": "Name" }],


             "bProcessing": true,
             "bServerSide": true,

             "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("FetchData", "Home")',
             "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

});
```

Can anyone please advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoted from the [API datatable page](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api) - on the [`fnReloadAjax()`](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnReloadAjax) bullet:

> Note: To reload data when using server-side processing, just use the
>   built-in API function fnDraw rather than this plug-in.

Thus, you'd probably better use [`fnDraw`](http://datatables.net/api#fnDraw).

[EDIT] Actually, the order of your calls should be:

```
// you don't have to use $.json because you don't use the downloaded data
// first, ask the server to delete the data   
$.ajax({
   url: urlToDelete,
   success: function() {
       // if it worked, ask datatable to redraw the table with the new data
       $("#example").dataTable().fnDraw();
       // if this js function does anything useful (like deleting the row), then call it:
       Success();
   },
   error: function() {
       // display any error (like server couldn't be reached...), or at least try to log it
   }
});
```

Comment: i want to call the server side delete function. is there a better way to call that action?

Comment: then, you should call it *before* asking for a redraw. I'll edit my answer to be clearer

Comment: as before, it can go into success function but it doesn't refresh the datatable?

Comment: with `fnDraw`, it should. Could you tell us where it doesn't work in debug? did you try to add some debug printing or firebug console within several points there?

Comment: yes, i did. the trick was $("#example").dataTable().fnDraw();

Comment: glad you figured it out. I've edited my answer with the correct statement for fellow users

Comment: $("#example").dataTable().api().ajax.reload() must work too I think

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this issue with much simple approach than provided in above answers.

**Ajax call to delete data from backend**

First of all delete the data from backend using normal ajax async call.

**Delete from frontend datatable**

Get the row TR which you want to delete and use the datatable function [`fnDeleteRow`](https://datatables.net/api) to delete this row. This will automatically refresh the table so you will not need any `fnDraw` or other stuff.

```
//in my case its delete button which was clicked 
//so I got its parents parent which is TR row
var row = $(this).parent().parent();


$('DATA TABLE SELECTOR').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(row);
```

And you are done.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer here didn't work for me, so I used this:

http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnReloadAjax

Add this to a file:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function ( oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw )
{
    if ( sNewSource !== undefined && sNewSource !== null ) {
        oSettings.sAjaxSource = sNewSource;
    }

    // Server-side processing should just call fnDraw
    if ( oSettings.oFeatures.bServerSide ) {
        this.fnDraw();
        return;
    }

    this.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, true );
    var that = this;
    var iStart = oSettings._iDisplayStart;
    var aData = [];

    this.oApi._fnServerParams( oSettings, aData );

    oSettings.fnServerData.call( oSettings.oInstance, oSettings.sAjaxSource, aData, function(json) {
        /* Clear the old information from the table */
        that.oApi._fnClearTable( oSettings );

        /* Got the data - add it to the table */
        var aData =  (oSettings.sAjaxDataProp !== "") ?
            that.oApi._fnGetObjectDataFn( oSettings.sAjaxDataProp )( json ) : json;

        for ( var i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ )
        {
            that.oApi._fnAddData( oSettings, aData[i] );
        }

        oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();

        that.fnDraw();

        if ( bStandingRedraw === true )
        {
            oSettings._iDisplayStart = iStart;
            that.oApi._fnCalculateEnd( oSettings );
            that.fnDraw( false );
        }

        that.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, false );

        /* Callback user function - for event handlers etc */
        if ( typeof fnCallback == 'function' && fnCallback !== null )
        {
            fnCallback( oSettings );
        }
    }, oSettings );
};
```

Include the file on your page and call like this:

```
// Example call to load a new file
oTable.fnReloadAjax( 'media/examples_support/json_source2.txt' );

// Example call to reload from original file
oTable.fnReloadAjax();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instance of dataTable and remove row from datatable

```
dataTable.fnDeleteRow($(that).closest('tr').remove());
dataTable.fnDraw();
```