# How to get partialview data in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

in my MVC 4 web apps, I have a model data with a jQuery tab table, in each tab, I have some embedded tables which works as one to many relationship with this main tab table, in main tab table, I have a button ("Add"), when click it, a row of data field beside it with the  data user entered will be added to the children table (which is a partialview) embedded in one of tab table, now, the code behind the button and controller saved the data to table, but the current embedded does not updated to show the new added table data at all. I appreciate anybody can help me out this problem.
This is the javascript behind Add button,

```
  function AddMeal() {

    //Build your Product
    var product = { "MDate": $("#MDate").val(), "MRegion": $("#MRegion").va(), "MBAmount":       $("#MBAmount").val(), 
            "MLAmount": $("#MLAmount").val(), "MDAmount": $("#MDAmount").val(), "FINtravelID":               $("#FINtravelID").val() };

    $.post('@Url.Action("Edit1","Travel")', product, function (data) {

    if (data == null) {
        location = location.href;
    }
    else {
        //Populate your MealTable element with the results of your Partial View
        $('#MealTable').html(data);
    }
});}
```

This is controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit1( Meal product)
    {

        db.Meals.Add(product);
        db.SaveChanges();  
        ViewBag.SaveMeal = "1";
        return PartialView("_MealPartial", product);

    }
```

this is the razor view related to this question,

```
        @model Travelmvc.Models.FINtravel
        <input type="button" value="Add" id="AddButton1"  onclick="AddMeal()"/>
       <div id="MealPartial">

       @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_MealPartial.cshtml")

       </div>
```

This is partialview details codes:

```
   @model Travelmvc.Models.FINtravel
      <table class="MealT" id="MealTable" >
       @if (Model != null) {
             if (Model.Meals != null){ //here this line code always returns null, that is why the    
        read data created in SQL table can not display in the loop

       foreach (var item in Model.Meals)
             {

                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MRegion)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MBAmount)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MLAmount)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MDAmount)
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MTAmount)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MProduct)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MRC)
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MLocation)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MPOC)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        aa
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ff
                    </td>
                </tr>
             } 
...
```

and this is the model of FINtravel and Meal.

```
public class FINtravel
{

   public int FINtravelID { get; set; }

   public string ClaimNo { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Meal> Meals { get; set; }
}

public class Meal
{
    public int MealID { get; set; }
    public int FINtravelID { get; set; }
    public virtual FINtravel FINtravel { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is why the meal data created in Edit1 controller not display in razor view (partialview)?  But I can see the data was saved in SQL table from back end.
can anybody help me out of this problem? thank a lot in advance.

Comment: Your `_MealPartial` view is of `FINtravel` model but you are passing a `Meal` model to it?

Comment: Try to `refresh` the jquery datatable. Look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8648886/873979)

Comment: Hi WannaCSharp, thanks a lot, yes, I  realized it, but do not know how to pass the correct model based on this relationship. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can try change your controller code like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit1( Meal product)
{

    db.Meals.Add(product);
    db.SaveChanges();  
    product = db.Meals.Find(product.MealID);//get saved product with filled property FINtravel
    ViewBag.SaveMeal = "1";
    return PartialView("_MealPartial", product.FINtravel);
}
```

Comment: Hi, good points, but I just tried it, but the run time error stopped on line of "foreach (var item in Model.Meals) " in partialview with error message of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", obviously, the Model.Meals is null in debug mode, I also debugged controller, "return PartialView("_MealPartial", product.FINtravel);" // product.CMHCtravel is null, that is why I got null in partialview side, By the way, in my partial and normal view, I have @model Travelmvc.Models.FINtravel on top,

Answer (score 0):

```
  fintravel = db.FINtravel.Find(product.FINtravelID);//
  return PartialView("_MealPartial", fintravel);
 solves the problem, thanks for all helps in this thread
```